# Java library or text file that maps mime types to nice human friendly file types

Tags: java, text, types, mime-types

GOAL
My goal is to find a text file or library that enables me to map when given a mime type input and return a nice human friendly format.

For example given the mime type for Word (as shown below) I would like a result that is something like "Microsoft Office Word Document".

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

I realise I could compile my own list and use something like a Map (Java) but then it would not be comprehensive etc.

SIMPLISTIC OPTION
I know I can examine and return the sub mime type and keep the last component but that is not very sophisticated as per the Word mime type above the result would be a very generic "document". I could expand and take more components but the result is still quite ugly.

KEY/VALUE FILE
Another option I have tried to find is a text file with key/value pairs where the key is the mime type in full and the value being the nice human friendly text.

```
text/plain=Plain Text File
application/octet-stream=Unknown binary file
```

This seems like a nice option but I have not been able to find a definitive text file with lots of entries. It would also be nice if a source for just the media( i prefer to call it the primary mime type) the "text" in "text/plain" was present so an unknown text mime type such as "text/unknown a.b.c" would return "Unknown text file/format".

Comment: retagged, more tags may help you have more answers.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following links might save you some time:

- http://help.dottoro.com/lapuadlp.php
- http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMimeTypesAndApplications.html
- http://www.hansenb.pdx.edu/DMKB/dict/tutorials/mime_typ.php

And here are a couple of links that maps mime types and the file extensions:

- http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml
- http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Comment: The dottoro and pdx-edu links are fairly good but hardly comprehensive.. any chance you have a more complete link ? Im not interested in lists that only give mime type = file extensions...

Answer (score 3):

Apache Tika supports [MimeTypes](http://tika.apache.org/0.7/api/org/apache/tika/mime/MimeTypes.html). It also supports [Content Detection](http://tika.apache.org/0.7/detection.html) by the way if you don't know the mime type. Anyway, it looks like you need to do:

```
String t = "text/plain";
org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypes.getMimeType(t).getDescription();
```

Disclaimer: I didn't actually try it. Also, I don't know if it supports all mime types you need.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Inside tika-core.jar theres an xml file tika-mimetypes.xml which has a lot of mime types and descriptions defined within it. It looks like it should work... thanx again!

Comment: Most of the entries in the xml are ignored because for some strage reason tika is setting descriptions from tags called "_comment" but not "description" etc. Going to file an issue/patch..

Comment: this appears to be fixed from version 0.8 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-515)

Answer (score 0):

Use this library

this works by files,bytes,...

MimeUtil >
https://github.com/saces/MimeUtil

usage:

```
MagicMimeMimeDetector g = new MagicMimeMimeDetector();
Collection<MimeType> list =  g.getMimeTypes(file);

if(list.size() > 0)
{
    MimeType mime = list.iterator().next();
    return mime.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this in 2023 or later this looks like a more official and definitive resource for the mappings:

https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

However, if you're looking for a Java library, you can't go wrong with Apache Tika in Java, as already suggested.